# Airflow: DAG marked as success although one task failed

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

A similar question has been asked before but as far as I can tell, it can't be explained by this answer since I don't have any tasks with "all_done" trigger rule.

[image]

As seen from the image above, a task has failed but that DAG is still marked as a success. The trigger rule for all the tasks but one is the default one.

Any idea how to mark the whole DAG as Failed in such case?

Comment: Can you change the trigger rule from one_success to none_failed and try?

Comment: I'm running Airflow 1.10.1 (on Cloud Compsoer)  and I think that none_failed is from a later version